# Fetch API data with react and filter search input with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, gatsby

I have a question regarding a React filter search input.

I have two Components the the moment.

**FirstPageComponent.js**

```
import React from "react"
import AutoComplete from "./AutoComplete"

export class FirstPageComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      rows: [],
      loading: true,
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount(searchTerm = "marvel") {
    await fetch(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=&query=" +
        searchTerm
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({
          rows: responseData.results,
          loading: false,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error fetching and parsing data", error)
      })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.rows)
    return <AutoComplete movies={["hej"]} />
  }
}
```

and

**AutoComplete.js**

```
import React from "react"

export default class AutoComplete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rows: [],
      loading: false,
      userInput: "",
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    const { movies } = this.props
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value

    const rows = movies.filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    )

    this.setState({
      rows,
      loading: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value,
    })
  }

  onClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      rows: [],
      loading: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      state: { rows, loading, userInput },
    } = this
    let moviesListComponent
    if (loading && userInput) {
      if (rows.length) {
        moviesListComponent = (
          <ul>
            {rows.map((movie, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} onClick={onClick}>
                  {movie}
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )
      } else {
        moviesListComponent = (
          <>
            <p>Couldn't find any movies. Try searching for another movie.</p>
          </>
        )
      }
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="search" onChange={onChange} value={userInput} />
        {moviesListComponent}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

- I basically want to know if i’m approaching this the right way. I want to make a dynamic request for movie titles from fetch(”https://themovie.db”) API.
- Send down the movie titles as props and then filter the values in autocomplete component if the user input is similar to the movie title props.

Am i thinking about this the right way? I've tried to have the fetch call in the same component as AutoComplete but haven't gotten it to work as i want it to. How would you setup the component structure if you'd be solving this issue for example?

Feel free to ask if there’re any confusions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

These are my assumptions about the above code, let me know if any are incorrect.

- You're doing an initial API request for a list of movies by search term. That search term is given outside of the code above and doesn't change by any mechanism above.
- You're further filtering the data returned by the API request dynamically via the `AutoComplete` component.

Most of your React code here looks pretty good, but I've got some recommendations:

1. In general, I find it's best to keep the list of things completely separate, so I would create a separate `MovieList` function component that simply takes an array of `movie` objects, and a `titleFilter` string and renders them.
2. `componentDidMount` doesn't take arguments. `searchTerm` should be a prop of `FirstPageComponent` (presumably set by the parent component by some kind of selection or user input)
3. I'd rename `AutoComplete` to `TitleFilter` or the like. It's not really auto-completing, it's more of a filter field.
4. This line: `if (loading && userInput) {` will result in displaying no movies when the user hasn't yet filled in text into the filter field. I'm not sure that is what you would want.
5. This line is a bit misleading: `<p>Couldn't find any movies. Try searching for another movie.</p>` because you could have just filtered out all the results returned. In this case, it wasn't that you couldn't find movies, it's that your filter is too restrictive.
6. For the `onClick` handler, I'm not sure such a general approach is best. It could create a strange interaction if you were to somehow click on the `<ul>`, for example. To improve this, I'd recommend each movie row component implement its own `onClick` and call a function to set the filter.
7. You're going to have to deal with pagination on this, I'd bet. Check your API and see what it does for that and make sure you're accounting for it.

Small nits:

1. `userInput: e.currentTarget.value,` could be shortened to `userInput,`, which is shorthand for `userInput: userInput,` (you already have a variable named `userInput`.)
2. For `key` props, an actual unique id would be better, in the case you change your filtering and index numbers don't line up with the unique rows you're rendering anymore.
3. I like to go ahead and create a separate component for each row, so I'd make a `MovieRow` function component which takes a `movie` object and renders it. It just keeps the code a bit cleaner. (and makes #6 above easier to implement)

Comment: Nice, a lot to go through. Will look into it and reach back to you if necessary!